# how to find differentially methylated regions (for example with probe lasso in Champ) based on regression continuous variable ~ beta (with CpGassoc)

Tags: r

I performed 450K Illumina methylation chips on human samples, and want to search for the association between a continuous variable and beta, adjusted for other covariates. For this, I used the CpGassoc package in R. I would also like to search for differentially methylated regions based on the significant CpG sites. However, the probe lasso function in the Champ package and also other packages for 450K DMR analyses always assume 2 groups for which DMRs need to be find. I do not have 2 groups, but this continuous variable. Is there a way to load my output from CpGassoc in the probe lasso function from Champ? Or into another bump hunter package? I'm a MD, not a bio-informatician, thus comb-p, etc. would not be possible for me.

Thank you very much for your help.

Kind regards,
Line

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with methylation data before, so take what I say with a grain of salt. Also, don't use acronyms without describing them I'm guessing most people on this site don't know what a DMR is.

you could use lasso from the `glmnet` package to run a lasso on your data. So if your continuous variable was age you could do something like. If `meth.dt` is your methylations data.table with your columns as the amount of methylation for a given site, and your rows as subjects. I'm not sure if methylation data is considered to be poisson, I know RNA-seq data is. I also can't get too specific but the following code should work after adjusting to your number of columns

```
  #load libraries
  library(data.table)
  library(glmnet)

  #read in data
  meth.dt <- fread("/data")

  #lasso
 AgeLasso <- glmnet(as.matrix(meth.dt[,1:70999,with=F]),meth.dt$Age, family="poisson")
 cv.AgeLasso <- cv.glmnet(as.matrix(meth.dt[,1:70999,with=F]), meth.dt$Age, family="poisson")
 coefTranscripts <- coef(cv.AgeLasso, s= "lambda.1se")[,1][coef(cv.AgeLasso, s= "lambda.1se")[,1] != 0]
```

This will give you the methylation sites that are the best predictors of your continuous variable using a parsimonious model. For additional info about `glmnet` see http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html

Also might want to ask the people over at cross validated. They may have some better answers. http://stats.stackexchange.com

What is your continuous variable just out of curiosity?

Let me know how you ended up solving it if you don't use this method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ultimately still ended up using comb-p with the help from a bio-informatician from my university. Still, thank you for your help!